# Select nearest but not greater-than row

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table action(start:DATE, length:NUMBER, type:NUMBER), with all records unique, I need to select (e.g.) length of last action with type Y before time X:

```
select action.length 
 where action.type = Y 
   and action.start is the biggest, but not greater than X
```

Proposed solution (improved):

```
  with actionView as (select * from action where type = Y and time <= X) 
select length
  from actionView
 where time = (select max(time) from actionView)
```

But this still envolves two selects.

What I would like to ask is it possible to perform some analytical or hierarchical or any other oracle magic to this query, to improve it?

(Probably, something like this algo is what I need, but I don't know how to express it in SQL:

```
savedAction.time = MinimalTime
foreach action in actions
  if action.type = y and savedAction.time < action.time <= X
    savedAction = action
return savedAction;
```

)

Comment: you should look for LAG functions.  you can sort the data and compare to previous rows.  Also, you may be surprised that the optimizer is happier with thi structure than you are :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle has no `LIMIT` (PostgreSQL, MySQL) or `TOP` (SQL Server) clause like other RDBMS. But you can use ROWNUM for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT length 
    FROM   action
    WHERE  type = Y 
    AND    start < X
    ORDER  BY start DESC
    )
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

This way, the table will be queried once only.
[The details in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255).

---

In reply to Dems comment I quote from the link above:

> If you embed the ORDER BY clause in a subquery and place the ROWNUM
>   condition in the top-level query, then you can force the ROWNUM
>   condition to be applied after the ordering of the rows.

Comment: Does oracle really ***guarantee*** the order of the data in the outer query? If you had `rownum AS row_id` in the inner query, and then filtered the outer query by `row_id = 1`, then I'd trust the results to have a guaranteed behaviour.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter is there any real difference between Your solution and one by Dems (above)? I'm not sure there is semantic difference, but what about speed?

Comment: from oracle docs: `If you embed the ORDER BY clause in a subquery and place the ROWNUM condition in the top-level query, then you can force the ROWNUM condition to be applied after the ordering of the rows`

Comment: @Dems: It's explaining in the manual. Follow the link I provided. I added the relevant quote to my answer. It works the way I demonstrate, but would **not** work the way you suggest.

Comment: @RustemMustafin: Difference? `ROWNUM` is simpler, shorter and faster - and not standard SQL, so not portable to other RDBMS. With the window function `row_number()` you can do more complex stuff if needed - and it is standard SQL.

Comment: @A.B.Cade - Thanks for the info, slops to me for not reading the link! :-/

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Thanks for the link and quote! Why would it ***not*** work to have the rownum evaluated and aliased in the inner query?  I thought this pattern could be used in conjunction with `row_id >= 11 AND row_id < 21`, etc?  *(Sorry, can't test as I'm at a client with SyBase rather than Oracle.)*

Comment: @Dems: It really comes down to the same quote. The value for `ROWNUM` in the inner query is pre-`ORDER BY`. I have prepared a demo for you on sqlfiddle.com: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af258/3

Answer (score 2):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to evaluate this in a single scan...

```
WITH
  sequenced_data
AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY start DESC) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    action
  WHERE
    type = Y
    AND start < Z
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

You don't need the `PARTITION BY`, but it is used where you're getting the 'max' row per goup (such as per person, or item, in your database).

Comment: I suppose Your solution is very close to the one by Erwin (below). Is there any real difference?

Comment: @RustemMustafin - Erwin suggsts that RowNum is faster, which may be the case, you'd have to test, but I couldn't say either way myself.  Also, this can be expanded, as mentioned in the answer, to do this for multiple groups.  If you wanted the most recent clock-in for each of 1000 employees, this pattern yields all 1000 results in one query.

Comment: +1 and should be `partition by type` or you can eliminate partition by clause(is useless in this context),  and the where should be `start < X`

Comment: @FlorinGhita - My answer already describes that you don't need the `PARTITION BY`, and explains how it can be used (It's there as an example to be more informative).  As for `< Z` vs `< X`, I already used X in the `PARTITION BY` and they're just random letters, I can't see it mattering or confusing the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any magic, but:

```
  with (select length, time from action where type = Y and time <= X) as typed_action
  select length from typed_action
  where time = (select max(time) from typed_action)
```

Will give you less "where" clauses to execute and a (much?) smaller temporary typed_action table.

Comment: SQL is not executed directly, it is compiled into a plan.  This will likely have little or no effect on the end results; it's simply the same as specifying the `type = Y and time <= X` filter in the main queries.

Comment: @boisvert there are single-scan soutions mentioned above. What do You think about them?

Comment: @RustemMustafin, way neater than my solution; though you should index the time column to speed sorting, since performance is an issue. Also, if your filtered data is small, then sorting has no incidence, but if there is a lot of it, max is quicker.